# How to send Only App content - Privacy Policy to review - Not Production Build

Tags: google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console

Problem i am facing currently. I have updated the privacy policy URL and also i have updated the latest version for the production.

What i want is - I wanted to send Privacy policy link first for approval. Once the link is approved then Next i need to send the production build for approval.

[image]

Why i am doing this - Currently when i send both for approval. I am getting Invalid Privacy policy link Email - Even the Link is valid link.

[image]

I have tried all the possibilities and checked in settings - No option found to send the particular for review.